# Failed to resolve System.Int32 Xamarin.Essentials.Resource/Id::accessibility_action_clickable_span

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.essentials

When I compile the app in release mode I get the following error, I've already tried to reinstall and update all packages, but I still having problems with android in release mode. Any ideas? Thanks for any help :)

````
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedField (Mono.Cecil.FieldReference reference) [0x00013] in <3e53085892e04b628169d0ea2d9ff8b6>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkField (Mono.Cecil.FieldReference reference) [0x00024] in <3e53085892e04b628169d0ea2d9ff8b6>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction (Mono.Cecil.Cil.Instruction instruction) [0x0002e] in <3e53085892e04b628169d0ea2d9ff8b6>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody (Mono.Cecil.Cil.MethodBody body) [0x000c2] in <3e53085892e04b628169d0ea2d9ff8b6>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition method) [0x001b1] in <3e53085892e04b628169d0ea2d9ff8b6>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue () [0x0001b] in <3e53085892e04b628169d0ea2d9ff8b6>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue () [0x00047] in <3e53085892e04b628169d0ea2d9ff8b6>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue () [0x0000a] in <3e53085892e04b628169d0ea2d9ff8b6>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process () [0x000f6] in <3e53085892e04b628169d0ea2d9ff8b6>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x0000d] in <3e53085892e04b628169d0ea2d9ff8b6>:0 
  at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x0000b] in <3e53085892e04b628169d0ea2d9ff8b6>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context, Mono.Linker.Steps.IStep step) [0x0000d] in <3e53085892e04b628169d0ea2d9ff8b6>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x0000f] in <3e53085892e04b628169d0ea2d9ff8b6>:0 
  at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Run (Mono.Linker.Pipeline pipeline, Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in <3e53085892e04b628169d0ea2d9ff8b6>:0 
  at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process (MonoDroid.Tuner.LinkerOptions options, Mono.Linker.ILogger logger, Mono.Linker.LinkContext& context) [0x00071] in <3e53085892e04b628169d0ea2d9ff8b6>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute (Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver res) [0x001dd] in <3e53085892e04b628169d0ea2d9ff8b6>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask () [0x0001b] in <3e53085892e04b628169d0ea2d9ff8b6>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute () [0x00000] in <3e53085892e04b628169d0ea2d9ff8b6>:0  (XALNK7000) (vapaya.Android) ```
````

Comment: What is the Linking in Android options? If setting none, please try to change linking from "NONE" to "sdk and users assembly" and try again.

Comment: it was in "sdk and users assembly" already

Comment: I search some info, you can try to delete bin and obj folder in solution, restart visual studio to try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Delete bin and obj folder solved to me!